# How do I order by one column and then push latest chunk of same column id's to top?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

For example I have table:

```
|    id    |    title    |    created_at    |

     1                            12:00           
     2                            13:00
     2                            14:00
     1                            15:00
```

I want same id numbers to be near each other. In this case 1 1 2 2 or 2 2 1 1 AND order same chunks of id's by created_at time so the chunk of id's which own the latest created_at stays on top, then goes one, having highest created_at compared to 3rd chunk of id's and so on. How do I do it?

`orderBy('id', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();` // orders id's to same id chunks, but it doesn't sort that the chunk with latest id chunk (1 1) created_at at the top.

`orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();` // gives the latest created_at at top and so on, but same id's arent close to each other.

Bigger example:

```
|    id    |    title    |    created_at    |

 1                            12:00  
 2                            13:00
 1                            15:00
 2                            15:00
 1                            17:00
 3                            18:00
 1                            19:00
 3                            20:00
```

Want to anchieve that foreach($table_rows as $row) { } would give me result:

```
3    20:00
3    18:00
1    19:00
1    17:00
1    15:00
1    12:00
2    15:00
2    13:00
```

I know it's hard to do with mysql alone. How do I do this in php easiest way?

I bet I have to sort by id first and then push each id's chunk relative to each other by latest created_at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the information of the most recent date for each id.  Here is a method using `join` and an aggregation:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select t.id, max(created_at) as maxca
      from table t
      group by t.id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id
order by tt.maxca desc, id;
```

The rest is just the `order by` using the maximum value.

I don't know how to express this in laravel, but your question is also tagged mysql.

Comment: It does work, but inside groups each row is in reverse order. How do I group each group by created_at desc order?